# Windows Explorer keeps crashing in Windows 8.1

Tags: windows-explorer, windows-8.1

This started a few days ago on a machine that has been running WIn 8.1 for over a month.

I just finished a clean install of Windows 8.1 with a handful of apps like Dropbox and Office. Yet I'm still getting Windows Explorer crashes such as this:

```
Faulting application name: Explorer.EXE, version: 6.3.9600.16408, time stamp: 0x523d251b
Faulting module name: SHELL32.dll, version: 6.3.9600.16409, time stamp: 0x523fac81
Exception code: 0xc00000fd
Fault offset: 0x0000000000189247
Faulting process id: 0xee8
Faulting application start time: 0x01ced2a62f6e5b2e
Faulting application path: C:\WINDOWS\Explorer.EXE
Faulting module path: C:\WINDOWS\system32\SHELL32.dll
Report Id: e25c6b13-3eb4-11e3-be7a-2cd05a597b87
Faulting package full name: 
Faulting package-relative application ID:
```

I assume that it is some sort of shell extension, but I don't know how to figure out which one.

Comment: 0xc00000fd = STACK OVERLOW. create dumps and upload them: http://pastebin.com/HAh45FFJ

Comment: I've got the same problem, please report if you fixed it.

Comment: same problem .. any fixes?